# How to select the particular list box item using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to select one of the list box item when user select the table row.

[image: This is my output aspx.page]

> The last item user added `SupplierCode` to a table by clicking `ADD Button`. When user want to modify the records from table, once they click that particular row, the value should move to **FilterValue** and Field in the list box should select that particular Field Name which is selected by user.
>
> Now user select the first row to modify the value. That value is moved to `FilterValue textbox`, But list box item is not selected automatically to `StoreID`

[image: see this pic]

But when I check the code in browser. it shows selected for that particular item which item user wants to select, but the color is not changed.

This is my code

**Jquery code**

```
    //SELECT Table ROW
$(document).on("click", '#queryTable tbody tr', function () {
    var tr = $(this);
    var FieldName = tr.find("td:first").text();
    var Values = tr.find("td:last").text();

    FieldName = FieldName.replace('AND ', '');
    FieldName = FieldName.replace('OR ', '');

    Values = Values.replace('IN(', '');
    Values = Values.replace(')', '');
    alert(FieldName + ' ' + Values);

    $("#FilterField option[value=" + FieldName + "]").attr("selected", true);
    $("#txtFilterValue").val(Values);
});
```

Comment: try  $("#FilterField").val(FieldName);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with following code and check if it works

```
 //SELECT Table ROW
$(document).on("click", '#queryTable tbody tr', function () {
    var tr = $(this);
    var FieldName = tr.find("td:first").text();
    var Values = tr.find("td:last").text();

    FieldName = FieldName.replace('AND ', '');
    FieldName = FieldName.replace('OR ', '');

    Values = Values.replace('IN(', '');
    Values = Values.replace(')', '');
    //alert(FieldName + ' ' + Values); provided your FieldName as correct value

    $("#FilterField").val(FieldName);
    $("#txtFilterValue").val(Values);
});
```

Comment: `#FilterField` is id of ListBox. How it will select the item?